# How do I stop a horizontal scroll bar from appearing in an IE9 text area?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

In IE 9, in a textarea box, when I am typing to the end of a row (right before a horizontal scroll bar is activated), I press enter to insert a new line to avoid the scroll bar but it still appears after the cursor moves to the new line.  How can I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Set wrap virtual like

```
<textarea cols=80 rows=12 wrap="virtual">
```

or Use CSS like

```
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Comment: `wrap="virtual"` is the default. The proposed CSS code does not seem to have an effect either.

Comment: Thanks for the input @JukkaK.Korpela :) . I was not aware that virtual was default. But it solved my problem many times that's why I suggested this.

Answer (score 1):

By default, IE 9 wraps text in `textarea` even breaking inside words when needed to make the text fit horizontally, and no horizontal scrollbar appears. So you must have something in your code to prevent this, probably the attribute `wrap=off`. In this case, a horizontal scrollbar indeed appears in the situation described. To prevent this, add

```
textarea { overflow-x: hidden }
```

But beware this implies that when a text longer than fits in the area is entered, it silently scrolls so that the start of the line is hidden. From usability perspective, this seems to be more serious than the problem fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your input,  I think a little more context to my problem would be helpful.  I do have wrap=off set, and I am doing this so that I can use JavaScript to manually insert line breaks as a way to control row length. It looks like IE 9 prematurely adds the horizontal scroll bars compared to other browsers, which is throwing of my script.  I think I'll just need to approach my problem in a different, less direct way.